# Change background colour when hovering a focused item

Tags: tailwind-css

I currently have this code:

```
    <li class="relative bg-white py-5 px-4 hover:bg-gray-50 focus-within:bg-blue-50/50 focus-within:ring-1 focus:bg-blue-50/50 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-blue-600">
```

Though when hovering a focused element, it will not change to a custom colour.

Is there a way to change to a custom background colour when hovering over a focused element?

Comment: How do you put focus on a `li` element? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was `focus-within:hover:bg-black` that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use any of the below class

```
hover:bg-["#fffeee"]
```

Or

```
focus:hover:bg-["#fffeee"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, if there is. You can check this link it will solve your problem.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#arbitrary-values

Your code would be as follows applying **Arbitrary values**

```
<li class="relative bg-white py-5 px-4 hover:bg-[#808080] focus-within:bg-blue-50/50 focus-within:ring-1 focus:bg-blue-50/50 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-blue-600"></li>
```

I hope it helps you.